# Analog to 1-channel Digital Converter

Tags: digital-logic, analog

I have 0-5 V analog value coming in, and I need to convert it to a high or low 5V digital signal.  Essentially, I need to create a 1-channel A/D converter.  The idea is that when my analog voltage goes above a certain threshold, it will set the digital output high, and vice-versa.  I saw something about being able to do this with op-amps, but I don't remember where I saw it.  I also want to do this without using a microcontroller.  Any ideas?

Comment: perfect job for a [comparator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparator)

Comment: Are you just requiring one-bit resolution i.e. the analogue signal is above or below a certain threshold voltage?

Comment: Yes, @Andyaka, that's all I need

Comment: Then you have an answer but think about how much hysteresis you need as shown in the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically you'd use a comparator for this. Or you could make a transistor version with a long-tailed pair.

A Schmitt-trigger would be a nice solution for a 0 to 5V input:

[image]
([Source](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_4/chpt_3/10.html))

But you pointed to an op-amp circuit...

Here's the idea. An opamp as a comparator with logic output.

[image]

It's worth reading through [ADI's application note](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/application_notes/AN-849.pdf) on that (source for the picture).

Their Conclusion is accurate in my opinion and worth bearing in mind:

"In conclusion, although op amps are not designed to be used as comparators, there are, nevertheless, many applications where the use of an op amp as a comparator is a proper engineering decision.
It is important to make an educated decision to ensure that the op amp chosen performs as expected"